# Cannot read property 'isArray' of undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, yeoman, typeahead.js

i am building an application using backbone,requirejs with yeoman.

am using twitter's typeaheadjs and getting this error **Randomly** ! Most of time it works but sometimes typeahead wont work without even throwing any error ! and the typeahead is not even working after **build**(grunt) This is the page where i call the typeahead

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'templates',
    ...
    'typeahead',
    ...
    ], function ( $, _, Backbone, JST, a, b, typeahead, c, d) {
```

This is the where i initialize the Typeahead which inside render() of a view

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success: function (data) {
        $('#SerachProduct').typeahead({
            name: 'abc',
            valueKey: 'name',
            local: data.toJSON(),
            template: JST['app/scripts/templates/typeahead.ejs']
        });
    },
    error: fun() {..
    }
}
```

Here is the github repo [Github](https://github.com/Anenth/Invoice-360)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeahead isn't AMD-compatibile, you'll need to define [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) configuration for it. It would be something like:

```
requirejs.config({
  // ...
  shim: {
    "typeahead": {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: 'jQuery.fn.typeahead'
    }
  }
});

define(['jquery', 'typeahead'], function ($, youCanIgnoreThis) {
  var opts = {
    // ...
  };
  $("#SearchProduct").typeahead(opts);
})
```

Read [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) for more details.

Comment: This worked in the development version ! Now the development version is working perfectly but after the build the typeahead is not working

Comment: That's not enough information to help you. I suspect this could be a separate problem which would warrant asking another question.